# Partial derivatives on area of a triangle

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, triangles

> Let $E(x,y)=\frac12\,xy\sin \omega$ be the area of a triangle,  where $\omega$ is the included angle of the two sides of length $x,\,y$. Evaluate partial derivatives
> $\frac{\partial E}{\partial x},\, \frac{\partial E}{\partial y},\,\frac{\partial E}{\partial \omega}$.

*Attempt*. I am looking for the relationship of $\omega=\omega(x,y)$ with $x,\,y$. Of course, $h=y\sin \omega$ is the height of the triangle, but this didn't help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find an expression for $\omega(x,y)$ because it doesn't exist. The angle between two sides is free to vary when only their lengths are specified.

Generally a triangle cannot be specified (up to an isometry) without three parameters (SAS, SSS work, for example).

I hope writing $E = E(x,y,\omega)$ will then make your problem simple.

Comment: Thank you. For sake of completeness, let me note that $E_x=\frac12 y\sin\omega$,  $E_y=\frac12 x\sin\omega$ and  $E_{\omega}=\frac12 xy\cos\omega$.